# Ask Emacs to create function (e.g. Eclipse/IntelliJ suggest/fix feature)

Tags: emacs, clojure, autosuggest

I am editing Clojure code in Emacs23, I am pretty new and I was wondering if there is a feature in Emacs to create missing function? It would be similar to Ctrl+1 in Emacs or Alt+Insert => Create method.

Answer (score 4):

what kind of "missing function" do you want to create? If you want to create empty function, then you can use any of snippet expansion packages, for example, yasnippet...

P.S. you can look onto [my snippets for clojure](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master/snippets/clojure-mode)...